# Homebrew - brew docter command not working

Tags: homebrew

When I installed wine I followed all the instructions, but then when I went to type 'brew docter' into terminal a error appears saying
Error: Unknown command: docter I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling it but the same appears.
what should I do?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `brew doctor` ?

Answer (score 1):

Check your spelling

it is not "docter"

it is "doctor"

So, you can try /usr/local/bin/brew doctor

Comment: just a honest mistake :), you should see my spelling before the spellchecker corrections.